# For convenience, how should I load a package whenever a specific other package loads?

Tags: package, autoload, require, eval-after-load

I have a package that enhances the functionality of another package.  To save the user the effort of any additional configurating, I would like my package to load automatically if the larger package loads.

(In my example, my package is a Flycheck checker, but I don’t think this situation will be specific to Flycheck checkers).

Is there a standard idiom for achieving this?

---

I find myself tempted to put the following at the end of my package:

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (unless (featurep 'flycheck-mychecker)
    (require 'flycheck-mychecker)))
```

Now, `package-lint` tells me:

> warning: `with-eval-after-load' is for use in configurations, and should rarely be used in packages

However, I couldn’t find an explanation of why this is typically bad in packages, and in what circumstances the “rarely used” exception should apply.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `autoload` for specific commands etc.
2. Use `require` if your library depends on another. That's the main question to ask yourself: does your library need the other library? If so, `require` it.

   You can also use a "soft-require" if you want to load another library whenever something is true. For example:

```lisp
(when (fboundp 'foobar) (require 'foo nil t))
```

3. Use `with-eval-after-load` (or `eval-after-load`) if you want to do something after some other library is loaded:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'bar
  ;; ...
  )
```

I imagine that the "rarely used" just means that most libraries explicitly use `require` or they autoload stuff. The doc of `with-eval-after-load` and `eval-after-load` describes their behavior, which in turn defines their use cases. Don't use them when you don't need them; that's all I think that "rarely used" intends.

On the other hand, presumably your package is intended to be optional. In that case, it's enough that a user explicitly loads it. And in that case all you need to do is `require` the larger package at the outset of your code.  I imagine that this is also part of what the text you quote intends.

---

A final note. If you want to load a library again, or load a library with the same name as one that's already been loaded (e.g. to pick up some other variant of version of it), then use `load-library`, not `require`.  And if you want to load the source file (`*.el`) then explicitly include the `.el` in the argument to `load-library`.

Comment: "presumably your package is intended to be optional" -- I admit that wasn't my intention.  I'd expect a user to want to configure which major modes a Flycheck checker applies to (which they can via customization), but I find it surprising that a user might want to install a package but never load it.

Comment: @mavit: It's optional whether to download, install, and load a package. Using a package (in any way) is a user choice - that was my point.